# xcowsay: how to use animated gif

Tags: bash, cowsay

Didn't find anything on google about `xcowsay` images and the man page doesn't specify about image types. i noticed that `/usr/share/xcowsay/` only has png files. I would like to use an animated gif file, but using them with `--image` option won't animate them. Is it possible?